# Formal definition of strictness

Tags: scala

I am reading the book functional programming in Scala and encounter following sentence:

> If the evaluation of an expression runs forever or throws an error
>   instead of returning a definite value, we say that the expression does
>   not terminate, or that it evaluates to bottom. A function `f` is
>   strict if the expression `f(x)` evaluates to bottom for all `x` that
>   evaluate to bottom.

What does the sentence mean? Can someone please show me an example?

Answer (score 3):

Strictness means that if an argument to a function is undefined, then the return value of the function is undefined. That's pretty much it.

The opposite is non-strictness, which means that an expression can have a value even if some of their sub-expressions are undefined.

The vast majority of programming languages are strict. However, most programming languages have at least one non-strict construct: boolean operators. For example, in Scala, this *will* be undefined (throw an exception):

```
def foo(bar: Boolean, baz: Boolean) = bar

foo(true, { throw new Exception; false })
```

Because `foo` is strict, but this won't:

```
true || { throw new Exception; false }
//=> res0: Boolean = true
```

Because `||` is non-strict in its second argument, which means that the return value can be defined even if some of the arguments are undefined.

Note: strict / non-strict is *not* the same as eager / lazy.